# MP3 file 'working' in some cases but not others

Tags: rust, mp3, playback, rodio

I using rust to get an MP3 file from a YouTube link using the `rusty_ytdl` crate, but using the `download` implementation from the `Video` struct results in a rather odd mp3 file. The file plays fine using windows' native media player, but trying to play it using the `rodio` crate results in an error with `Decoder`; `IoError("end of stream")`. Trying to play the file through VS Code also doesn't work, saying that `An error occured while loading the audio file.` Both the `rodio` crate and VS Code's native mp3 player work just fine with other MP3 files, and problems only occur with files downloaded through the `rusty_ytdl` crate. Why is this occuring and how do I fix it?
Edit: the mp3 file in question is https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sj0xxjh52ipnbapgcjit3/Amour.mp3?rlkey=dlaad2yauzd688d1lgy7k4tjb&dl=0

Comment: A quick check with `ffprobe Amour.mp3` reveals: `Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: *opus*, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)`. So this uses the opus codec, not mp3...

Comment: @rodrigo That explains things. I'll figure out a way to convert it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @baxtermaia5000 Why would you want to convert it?  Don't go from an already lossy format to yet another lossy format.  There is zero benefit.

Comment: @Brad I already wrote a command line mp3 player using the rodio crate as part of a bigger project, and rodio doesn't support the opus codec. I'd much rather do a stupid conversion than rewrite my entire mp3 player with a different crate.